# Node.js proxy response callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, callback

I want to be able to curl something from my machine to my server. The server should send another request to a different machine, and respond with that response. Something like a proxy. So for now I have (some parts obfuscated because of reasons):

```
internalHttpServer = _Http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   if(request is valid){
        pass_on_request(request, response); /** Sends the request on another server **/
        respond_with_data(request, response); /** how do I write this function to respond with the other result? **/
      }
  }
  respond_400(response);
});

function pass_on_request(req, res) {
 var id = get_id_to_request_from()
 list_of_other_connections[id].sendUTF(request)
 /** How do I send res with the results of this call? **/


connection.on('message', function(message) {
 /** what to do **/
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library like socket.io to keep the connection open.  It might also be available in HTTP2 when that is out.  With express you can't do that to my knowledge as it expects one answer from one request.

Comment: Okay, but the `other_connection` keeps a permanent channel open to the device i want to send to. So I cant listen for `onClose.` .. also, `res` is the first callback

Comment: Yeah, I saw that update after.  You should be able to use list_of_other_connections[id].on('message'... instead of close

Comment: Wait I see your issue now, I suppose in this case you can't use a restful API as it only sends one response.  You need to keep the connection open with something like socket.io http://socket.io/

Comment: I thought about that, and conclued that I probably need to keep a line open until done. Thanks!